# No partitions visible on external hard drive

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb, partition-table, sata

I'm trying to rescue data from Linux installation on old laptop. It was dual-booted with windows. I know there is at least 1 ntfs partition and 1 ext4. I can boot Windows on the old laptop, but linux is unusable.

I removed SSD and connected it via SATA to USB adapter to my current computer. But no partition is found. The device is connected via usb:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 18a5:0408 Verbatim, Ltd Store 'n' Go
```

and added to /dev/:

```
$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
```

but no partitions are found on sda:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT       
NAME        LABEL MOUNTPOIN
sda               
nvme0n1           
├─nvme0n1p1       
├─nvme0n1p2       
├─nvme0n1p3       
└─nvme0n1p4       
nvme1n1           
├─nvme1n1p1       /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p2       /
```

I know I'm looking at the right device because it appears and disappears when unplugged and plugged. Since I can boot Windows, partition table should be valid. Any ideas how to handle it?

Manjaro Linux, Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB, GPT partition table.